# Transposing individual elements of a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a python super dictionary that is made of individual dictionaries and currently looks like this:

```
raw_data1 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
raw_data2 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
raw_data3 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
top_dictionary = {
'raw_data1': raw_data1,
'raw_data2': raw_data2,
'raw_data3': raw_data3
}
print top_dictionary
```

I would like to transpose the individual dictionaries in my top_dictionary  in a way such that all the value fields get transposed to the Value Column and the date is appended as a row item. The column name of the value field becomes a row for the Description column.

As an example the value in top_dictionary with the key: 'raw_data1' will then look like:

```
raw_data1 = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-14','2017-03-14','2017-03-15','2017-03-15','2017-03-15'],'Value':[35.6,-7.8,24,56.7,56,-31,41,56,53,41,-3.4,5],'Desc':['SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M']}
```

I know how to do this for each individual dictionary by using the pandas melt function but how do I do this for my top_dictionary such that all elements inside it get transposed accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the top dictionary items. You'll have to play with if you want strict chronological order:

```
top_dict_new = dict()
for key, data_dict in top_dictionary.items():
    df = pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(data_dict), id_vars = ['Series_Date'])
    top_dict_new[key] = df.to_dict('list')
```

Edit:
This yields:

```
print top_dict_new['raw_data1']
{'variable': ['1M', '1M', '1M', '1M', '3M', '3M', '3M', '3M', 'SP', 'SP', 'SP', 'SP'], 'Series_Date': ['2017-03-10', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-15'], 'value': [-7.7999999999999998, 56.0, 56.0, -3.3999999999999999, 24.0, -31.0, 53.0, 5.0, 35.600000000000001, 56.700000000000003, 41.0, 41.0]}
```

Comment: But that creates a list, I would like to ensure that my underlining elements are in the same format and shape as I passed them

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The output of my code is the same as  your example output. In your example output, the dictionary for key "rawdata1" has lists as its items. I just updated my answer to show the output for key 'raw_data1' is the same. It is a dictionary where the items are lists same as your example output.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Series_Date" output... if you don't want it sorted, remove the sorted method in the function.  I only sorted it to match your specified output.

```
def make_dict(dict_in, val_cols):
    d_out = {}
    d_out['Value'] = pd.DataFrame(dict_in)[val_cols].values.flatten()
    d_out['Series_Date'] = sorted(dict_in['Series_Date'] * len(val_cols))
    d_out['Desc'] = val_cols * len(val_cols)
    return d_out

new_dict = {k: make_dict(v, ['SP','1M', '3M']) for k, v in top_dictionary.items()}
```